# Spark 3.0 Sort and apply on group Scala/Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-flink

I have spark DataSet lets see with columsn A,B,C

I want to take dataset

- Group on column A
- Sort Group (not whole dataset ) on column B
- Iterate over individual group look for some sequence/patter between consecutive N rows and based on critera return row which forms resulting dataset

### In Flink

```
dataset.groupBy(0).sortGroup(1, Order.ASCENDING)
                .reduceGroup({})
```

### In Pyspark

We can call apply function with Pandas on group and sort in pandas
However its very slow almos 10x compared to Flink

Note: I want to do processing over grouped data and return another dataset not standard aggregate

Can someone point me to similar code about how to do in java/scala in Spark ?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possible approaches depending on the iteration logic:

## Using Dataset API

Given

```
val df =
      Seq(("a", 0, "foo"), ("b", 1, "foo"), ("a", 1, "foobar"))
        .toDF("A", "B", "C")
```

first preprocess it a bit

```
df.select($"A", struct($"B", $"C") as $"S").show()
```

to get

```
+---+-----------+
|  A|          S|
+---+-----------+
|  a|   [0, foo]|
|  b|   [1, foo]|
|  a|[1, foobar]|
+---+-----------+
```

Now we can apply any Scala code to the sequence of tuples S including sorting:

```
df.select($"A", struct($"B", $"C") as $"S")
      .groupBy("A")
      .agg(collect_list("S"))
      .as[(String, Seq[(Int, String)])]
      .map {
        case (a, l) => (a, l.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2).maxBy(_.length))
      }
      .show()
```

## Using UDAFs

Implement a custom [UDAF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html):

```
class MyAgg extends Aggregator[
      (Int, String),
      mutable.ListBuffer[(Int, String)],
      /* any output type here */] {
...
```

and aggregate using that:

```
val myagg = udaf(new MyAgg())
df.select($"A", struct($"B", $"C") as "S").groupBy($"A").agg(myagg($"S"))
```

Comment: is there convenient way to sort records ? Also My agg dosent provide way to iterate over records in group

Comment: The records can be iterated in the `finish` method https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html

Comment: And AFAIK the sorting needs to be done just using Scala collection sorting like in the first snippet